# Mysql efficiently storing dynamic customer data in row or column

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

'customer_data' table:

```
id - int auto increment
user_id - int
json - TEXT field containing json object
tags - varchar 200

* id + user_id are set as index.
```

Each customer (user_id) may have multiple lines.
"json" is text because it may be very large with many keys or or not so big with few keys containing short values.
I usually search for the json for user_id.

Problem: with over 100,000 lines and it takes forever to complete a query. I understand that TEXT field are very wasteful and mysql does not index them well.

Fix 1:
Convert the "json" field to multiple columns in the same table where some columns may be blank.
Fix 2:
Create another table with user_id|key|value, but I may go into huge "joins" and will that not be much slower? Also the key is string but value may be int or text and various lengths. How to I reconcile that?

I know this is a pretty regular usecase, what are the "industry standards" for this usecase?

**UPDATE**

So I guess Fix 2 is the best option, how would I query this table and get one row result, efficiently?

```
id | key   | value
-------------------
1  | key_1 | A
2  | key_1 | D
1  | key_2 | B
1  | key_3 | C
2  | key_3 | E
```

result:

```
id | key_1 | key_2 | key_3
---------------------------
 1 |  A    |   B   |  C
 2 |  D    |       |  E
```

Comment: I think the second way is the best way. Even if the field value is a text, your query is going to be faster than now. If you read more than write, put an index in the field key of the new table.

Comment: @Enrique Just so it's clear the json is TEXT because it is being loaded from CSV file, it's a massive 20+ fields ranging from emails, to description to counts of various stuff. Do you think each should be TEXT? or very big varchar (like 500)? I thought the TEXT thing is what's killing me, shouldn't I avoid it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I suggest text because you said that: "Also the key is string but value may be int or text and various lengths". If "various lengths" is lower tahn 500 of course, better use a varchar(500)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a bit outside the box defined in your question, but I'd suggest:

Fix 3: Use MongoDB instead of MySQL.

This is not to criticize MySQL at all -- MySQL is a great structured relational database implementation.  However, you don't seem interested in using either the structured aspects or the relational aspects (either because of the specific use case and requirements or because of your own programming preferences, I'm not sure which).  Using MySQL because relational architecture suits your use case (if it does) would make sense; using relational architecture as a workaround to make MySQL efficient for your use case (as seems to be the path you're considering) seems unwise.

MongoDB is another great database implementation, which is less structured and not relational, and is designed for exactly the sort of use case you describe: flexibly storing big blobs of json data with various identifiers, and storing/retrieving them efficiently, without having to worry about structural consistency between different records.  JSON is Mongo's native document representation.

Comment: Color me intrigued :-) However at this point talking about migrating a big operation into a whole new DB might give my CEO a heart attack ... Still, I will look into it.

Comment: Relation database Postgres 9.4 has also excelent support for json - indexes, binary json/json data format. But migrating data to another database should be the last option